# Passing a Variant array to sub, "Expected: ="

Tags: vba, excel

I found a function to append a record to a table in Excel using VBA.  I have implemented it but I'm not familiar with the `Variant` data type.  I did some research and am attempting to use it as I would an array in VB but I keep getting a weird error that it's expecting an `=` sign.

[image]

Here is the code in non-screenshot form:

```
Sub AddDataRow(tableName As String, Values() As Variant)
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim table As ListObject
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Range

    Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set table = sheet.ListObjects.Item(tableName)

    'First check if the last row is empty; if not, add a row
    If table.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
        Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count).Range
        For col = 1 To lastRow.Columns.Count
            If Trim(CStr(lastRow.Cells(1, col).Value)) <> "" Then
                table.ListRows.Add
                Exit For
            End If
        Next col
    End If

    'Iterate through the last row and populate it with the entries from values()
    Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count).Range
    For col = 1 To lastRow.Columns.Count
        If col <= UBound(Values) + 1 Then lastRow.Cells(1, col) = Values(col - 1)
    Next col
End Sub

Sub btnNewGateway_Click()
    pName = Application.InputBox("Enter New Participant Name", "New Participant")
    Worksheets("TemplateGateway").Copy After:=Worksheets("TemplateGateway")
    ActiveSheet.Name = pName + " Gateway"
    Dim Values()
    v(0) = pName
    v(1) = "Gateway"
    v(2) = Today()
    AddDataRow ("tblOverview",????)

End Sub
```

Comment: First to your requested answer.  Remove the `()`.  The are not needed unless you use the `Call` method or have a variable you want to `=`.

Comment: Second you will get an error when you try to run it, You need to `dim v(0 to 2)`.  I would not use Values as it is close to a protect word, but that is preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need tu use

call AddDataRow(tbloverview, v)